# How to search YouTube for videos with English subtitles?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I was interested in learning German through YouTube videos in German with English subtitles.

Is there any way to do this through YouTube, Google or any other software?

Comment: I don't believe Google offers a way to find videos with certain audio languages with subtitles.  You are best investing in language software.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to search for videos with English captions only, but you can filter the search results to videos with subtitles by searching YouTube for the video you want to find, and then, from the search results page, open `Search options` / `Filter` and select the `Closed captions` option.

You'll still have to make sure that the video you want to watch includes *English* captions, but usually when a video includes captions, English is available.

For more information: [YouTube - About Captions and Subtitles](http://www.youtube.com/t/captions_about).

Answer (score 1):

The English cc (closed captions) are not yet very good on YouTube.  They use voice recognition and are generated on-the-fly.  What we want is what YouTube calls "annotations."  I have found that I can find movies with subtitles (annotations) by including the word "subtitle" in my search.  For instance, a search on "Disney subtitle" will result in about 24,400 results.  You'll need to refine your search because not all of the subtitles are English subtitles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amara:

http://www.amara.org/en/

Search for subtitles by language on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readsong; [www.readsong.com](http://www.readsong.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can search it with [spoketube.com](https://spoketube.com) - service to search YouTube video by speech.
It allows to search for whole channels (even several) and its database is constantly growing.
In addition, it allows you to search YouTube videos by title, description, tags and various filters.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way with new update to YouTube policies, as other people can add subtitles to others videos they get them self named for that.

Google it:
site:youtube.com "caption authors (English)"